# dropdown list in sencha touch2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I currently i am working on sencha touch 2. now i am facing a issue that's, i want to add dropdown list in itemTpl or list in below code.

```
itemTpl : [
           '<table border="1" style="width:100%; margin-top:0px;"><tr>',
           '<td style="width:10%; text-align: center; line-height: 2;  font-size: 10px;">here need to add Dropdown with store data</td>',
           '</tr></table>']
```

Pleaes help!

Thank's in advance.

Mukesh

Comment: ..you want to add it and? Where is the question?

Comment: Your post is not very clear, You cannot add a component directly in HTML, if you want to create a nested / dropdown list you should use a suitable component or extension. I think you should be looking at something like [Nested List](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/components/nested_list.html)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a component directly in HTML,But there is work around,follow below step

Just add selectfield as separate control in the form or container then run that page on browser,open developer tool inspect and copy whole html content of the selectfield with css class and paste that to itemtpl it will appear as sencha touch selectfield.

This is how i did that in one of my project.I know this is not standard way but some times you have to deal with workaround.

if you want i can share the code with you .

Hope this helps :)

Thanks
Sachin